# ¿Este programa cumple con su consigna? Arrays Java

Tags: java, array

estaba haciendo este programa de arrays :

- Escribir una línea de código que declare un *array* tipo `char` y lo inicialice con la constante de cadena `“Estudiando cadenas”`. El *array* debe tener un tamaño que permite guardar la cadena sin que sobre ningún elemento.

Lo hice así :

```
public class VectorChar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 final int TOPE = 16;

 final char arrayCaracter[]= {'E', 's', 't', 'u', 'd', 'i', 
                'a', 'n' ,'d', 'o' , 'c', 'a' , 'd', 'e', 'n' , 'a' , 's'};
  arrayCaracter = new char [TOPE];

    }

}
```

Lo que hice fue declarar un *array* tipo `char` con cada uno de sus caracteres de la cadena `"Estudiando cadenas"`; también puse una variable tope que es el que me va a indicar su dimensión ya que en total son 16 caracteres
 pero me daba error , entonces busque en Google ejemplos de *arrays* tipo `char` y lo cambie a esto:

```
public class VectorChar {

public static void main(String[] args) {


 final char arrayCaracter[]= {'E', 's', 't', 'u', 'd', 'i', 
                'a', 'n' ,'d', 'o' , ' ', 'c', 'a' , 'd', 'e', 'n' , 'a' , 's'};

 String salida = new String(arrayCaracter);

 System.out.println(salida);

    }
```

Lo único que deje fue la declaracion del *array* tipo `char`, lo de `String` lo vi en un ejemplo, por lo que  probe y me funcionó, pero mi pregunta es si realmente en el último cambio que realicé en el programa es lo que me pide en la consigna.

Comment: Pareceria que si. pero no tiene mas respuesta que eso.. estas cosas las podes preguntar en el [chat]. Esta pregunta no tiene mas respuesta que un si o un no. No tiene una duda real.

Comment: En general, si produce el resultado esperado, entonces, si es lo que había que hacer.

Comment: Seguro es la consigna completa? Lo que me hace ruido es que inicializando el array de la forma que lo hiciste (que no está mal) no hay forma que el array sea mas grande que la "cadena" ingresada. Sería diferente si tuvieras que pasar una cadena como parámetro, crear un array del tamaño de la cadena, y guardar ahí los caracteres que componene la misma. Por último, y para ser estricto con tu pregunta, la consigna no dice nada de crear un String e imprmir el resultado.

Comment: Claro por eso no sabia como hacerlo la consigna no me dice nada de mostrar por consola lo que hice , entonces con declarar el array tipo char  con su cadena de caracteres ya estaria completo el programa(?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad lo que te están pidiendo es que hagas algo similar a esto:

```
String cadena = "Estudiando cadenas";
char[] array = new char[cadena.length()];
cadena.getChars(0, cadena.length(),array, 0);
```

Donde primeros declaras el String con la cadena que te dan, luego creas un array de char con el tamaño de la cadena y a continuación lo rellenas usando la función getChars

Comment: Muchas Gracias ahora entendí , saludos :D !!!

Comment: Si ese es el caso, creo que sería mejor hacer `char[] array = cadena.toCharArray()`

Comment: Si, en caso de tener que programarlo yo también lo haría así, pero de la forma que puse hace exactamente lo que le piden.